# How to override CSS in nested HTML document?

Tags: html, css

I have some embedded youtube videos that has pesky youtube-added attributes to the title bar that I would like to get rid of (if it's even possible). Upon publishing, a nested HTML document is generated inside the `<iframe>` tag that contains the youtube video. How do I get at the CSS for that nested document? I'd appreciate an answer in CSS if possible but if the only way to get at it is JS or JQuery then I would be able to implement that.

Example of code generated. How would I get at class `ytp-gradient-top` and override it, presumably with my own class on the iframe `youtube-video` (doesn't have to be that, just assuming that's what I would need to do)?:

```
<iframe class="youtube-video" src="https://..."
    #document
      <html>
         <head></head>
         <body id class="blahblahblah">
             <div id="player">
                <div>
                  <div>
                   <div>
                     <div class='ytp-gradient-top'>
//all the closing divs, body, html, etc
</iframe>
```

Comment: Check out [How to apply CSS to iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe) as a starting place.

Comment: @benvc thanks for the link. Sounds like it's not possible for me to override it since the iframe isn't coming from the same domain. Bummer